# preserving aliases in laravel query builder

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, query-builder

```
function getPerson(){
    return \DB::table('user')->select('firstname as name', 'age');
}

function getPet(){
    return \DB::table('pet')->select('petname as name', 'age');
}

function getNames($var){
    return $var->select('name')->where('age', 10)->get();
}

$base = getNames(getPerson());//empty here
$base = getNames(getPet());//empty here
```

The main problem is I got a lot of different queries and I want to put aliases on them and then prepare data for diagram with another query. It is difficult if aliases diseappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each query can have only one `select()`. `$var` being passed into `getNames()` is a query already has `select()` so adding more `select()` will override previous one.

Try remove `select()` from `getNames()` and test whether you get your result.

```
function getNames($var){
    return $var->where('age', 10)->get();
}
```

Remember that you are using 'query builder' which means every query constraint you are adding is being added into the same query, not different one. The entire query will be actually built and executed once you try to get the result data set like calling `get()`, `first()`, etc.

Comment: So is there a way to perform a nested select?

Comment: As I am aware, nested select is not directly supported by Eloquent. Need to use some raw SQL while building the query. So it depends on final SQL you want to achieve. Try google "eloquent nested select", there are some examples around.